# Activate Data-Error attribute manually

Tags: materialize

Is it possible to activate the data-error in label manually using javascript?

What i am trying to do is check if two input fields are same and if not trigger data-error in the label.

html

```
<input id="email" type="email" class="validate">
<label for="email">Email</label>
<input id="check_email" type="email" class="validate">
<label for="check_email" data-error="Re-typed email must match">Re-type email</label>
```

In my javascript i basically check if check_email value matches email value. If not that is when i want to activate the data-error.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add the following to your JS if check_email value does not match email value:

```
$("#check_email").addClass("invalid");
$("#check_email").prop("aria-invalid", "true");
```

You can refer this [codepen](http://codepen.io/pratikms/pen/BKJzVY) for better clarity

Answer (score 2):

I have been struggling with this problem for hours, until I find this kinda naive and brute-force solution:

```
$("#signinUsername").next("label").attr('data-error','The name field is required');
$("#signinUsername").removeClass("valid");
$("#signinUsername").addClass("invalid");
```

Ugly-looking as it is, it works.

Comment: This does not work as expected. The data-error moves around when it's clicked on, just like the labels do.

Comment: When the field is empty, it does. I have also tackled this problem by modifying css somehow. Anyway, I eventually quit using materialize because it has got too many weird problems like this one...